# Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out in Ubuntu 16.04.6

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, ubuntu-16.04

On ubuntu 16.04.6 on trying to mask a systemd service. I am seeing errors like below.

```
systemctl mask hadoop-hdfs-zkfc.service
Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
```

I am using the default systemd version that comes with Ubuntu 16.04.6.

```
ubuntu@platform1:~$ systemctl --version
systemd 229
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP
+LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS
+KMOD -IDN
```

The issue does not come always. But once this issue is hit the only way to recover the systemd is to do a hard-reboot.

Looking at the syslog it appears systemd aborted.

```
May 18 08:49:24 platform3 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of support.
May 18 08:49:27 platform3 systemd[1]: Assertion 's->type ==
SERVICE_ONESHOT' failed at ../src/core/service.c:1792, function
service_enter_start(). Aborting.
May 18 08:49:27 platform3 systemd[1]: Caught <ABRT>, dumped core as pid 15839.
May 18 08:49:27 platform3 systemd[1]: Freezing execution.
```

`busctl` output looks like below

```
ubuntu@platform3:~/logs$ busctl
NAME                               PID PROCESS         USER             CONNECTION    UNIT                      SESSION    DESCRIPTION
:1.1                               976 systemd-logind  root             :1.1          systemd-logind.service    -          -
:1.3                               971 accounts-daemon root             :1.3          accounts-daemon.service   -          -
:1.5434                          49174 systemctl       root             :1.5434       cron.service              -          -
:1.5435                          49223 systemctl       root             :1.5435       ssh.service               -          -
:1.5436                          49408 busctl          ubuntu           :1.5436       ssh.service               -          -
:1.7                              1109 unattended-upgr root             :1.7          unattended-upgrades.se... -          -
com.ubuntu.LanguageSelector          - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.debian.AptXapianIndex            - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.Accounts           971 accounts-daemon root             :1.3          accounts-daemon.service   -          -
org.freedesktop.DBus               936 dbus-daemon     messagebus       org.freedesktop.DBus dbus.service              -          -
org.freedesktop.hostname1            - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.locale1              - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.login1             976 systemd-logind  root             :1.1          systemd-logind.service    -          -
org.freedesktop.network1             - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.resolve1             - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.systemd1             - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.thermald             - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.timedate1            - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
```

Can someone let me know, how to debug this?

The issue looks similar to the one discussed [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9315). So is this some known systemd issue on Ubuntu 16.04.6?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has been anaswered systemd mailing list. Cross-posting the answer

> This bug (https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4444) was fixed in
>   systemd v236.
>
> See if you can use a newer version of systemd.